# Godot: Check if mouse cursor is inside viewport

Tags: godot

In Godot 3.2, how do you check whether the mouse cursor is currently inside the root viewport (project is running in a windowed viewport, not fullscreen)?

I've researched that a [`Viewport`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.2/classes/class_viewport.html) can be a child of a [`ViewportContainer`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.2/classes/class_viewportcontainer.html) which itself inherits a [`has_focus()`](https://docs.godotengine.org/de/3.2/classes/class_control.html#class-control-method-has-focus) method - but the root viewport doesn't have a container. Even then I'm not sure if this would capture the mouse motion, since the [available focus modes](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.2/classes/class_control.html#enum-control-focusmode) only include "grabbing focus on mouse click or using the arrows and the Tab keys on the keyboard".

Another approach would be to evaluate the viewport's size and position on the screen vs. the mouse position in screen coordinates - but I can't find the right methods that give me screen-global coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of the `NOTIFICATION_WM_MOUSE_ENTER` and `NOTIFICATION_WM_MOUSE_EXIT` notifications. [Here's the docs](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_mainloop.html?highlight=NOTIFICATION_WM_QUIT_REQUEST#constants).

This may or may not work until the mouse enters/exits for the first time--in my tests, I sometimes got a MOUSE_ENTER notification, and sometimes I didn't. If this is important to you, you could work around it by detecting mouse motion in the window.